# Visual studio Class not found exception and namespace not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

Im having an issue where my c# program builds and compiles successfully but fails at runtime. It gives this exception whenever i run it.

[image]

Im also getting "type or namespace not found" for my LinkExplorer dll (during runtime) but im able to reference it and it doesnt give me any error when compiling / building. Why is it giving namespace not found when the namespace clearly exists? I also tried build target = x64 and x86 but still gives the same error. My .NET is 4.0 which is the same as this dll's.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In project properties -> Build tab, you need to mark your project to be registered for COM interop:

[image]

and in Application tab, click Asembly information... and at the bottom of a pop up check:

[image]